# Matlab: how I can transform this algorithm associated with matrices manipulation?

Tags: matlab, matrix

(For my problem, I use a matrix `A`  `4x500000`. And the values of A(4,k) varies between 1 and 200).

I give here an example for a case `A` 4x16 and A(4,k) varies between 1 and 10.

I want first to match a name to the value from 1 to 5 (=10/2):

```
1 = XXY;  
2 = ABC; 
3 = EFG;  
4 = TXG; 
5 = ZPF;
```

My goal is to find,for a vector X, a matrix M from the matrix A:

```
A = [20 52 70 20 52 20 52 20 20 10 52 20 11  1 52 20
     32 24 91 44 60 32 24 32 32 12 11 32  2  5 24 32
     40 37 24 30 11 40 37 40 40  5 10 40 40  3 37 40
      2  4  1  3  4  5  2  1  3  3  8  6  7  9  6 10]
```

A(4,k) takes all values between 1 and 10. These values can be repeated and they all appear on the 4th line.

```
   20
X= 32 =A(1:3,1)=A(1:3,6)=A(1:3,8)=A(1:3,9)=A(1:3,12)=A(1:3,16)
   40 

A(4,1) = 2;  
A(4,6) = 5;
A(4,8) = 1;
A(4,9) = 3;
A(4,12) = 6;
A(4,16) = 10;
```

for A(4,k) corresponding to X, I associate 2 if A(4,k)<= 5, and 1 if A(4,k)> 5. For the rest of the value of A(4,k) which do not correspond to X, I associate 0:

```
        [ 1  2  3  4  5   %% value of the fourth line of A between 1 and 5
          2  2  2  0  2
   ZX =   6  7  8  9 10   %% value of the fourth line of A between 6 and 10
          1  0  0  0  1
          2  2  2  0  2 ] %% = max(ZX(2,k),ZX(4,k))
```

the ultimate goal is to find the matrix M:

```
M = [  1     2     3     4     5 
      XXY   ABC   EFG   TXG   ZPF
       2     2     2     0     2 ]   %% M(3,:)=ZX(5,:)
```

Comment: Did you try any code yet? Where did you fail? Do you need the matrix `ZX` in this form or is just the correct result of `M` required? Next, you cannot insert `strings` (your names) into an `array`. You need to use `cells`. Also, from your description it seems, as if the first two lines of `M` are always the same? Is it possible that you have more (or less) than five names? In this case (e.g. 4 names), do the values from `A(4,k)` only range from `1..8`? You need to describe your problem and your boundary conditions more precisely.

Comment: @Nemesis: For programming, I'm used to working only with for loops, while I am still surprised by faster methods on this forum !! I only need the matrix M as a result. The first two lines of the matrix M are always the same. for the example I gave, the values of A(4,k) vary only between 1 and 10.

Comment: Is there a connection between `vector X` and the `X` in `XXY`? How are we supposed to generate the names which are the second row elements in `M`. So would `M` be a cell array, because with the strings for the second row, it appears it should be?

Comment: @Divakar: No connection between X and XXY, XXY is a name associated to 1. The second line of M contains names corresponding to 1,2,3,4 and 5 at the beginning of the question. Yes M is a cell array, but I do not know if it's possible to have M as given in the question.

Comment: So, we can assume that the names - `XXY   ABC   EFG   TXG   ZPF` are given to us and we don't need to generate those in the solution?

Comment: @Divakar: yes the names are given but since in my real problem I have 100 names, I would like to have a visual representation of these names with the third line of M.

Comment: Check out how the posted solution works out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code -

```
%// Assuming A, X and names to be given to the solution
A = [20 52 70 20 52 20 52 20 20 10 52 20 11  1 52 20
    32 24 91 44 60 32 24 32 32 12 11 32  2  5 24 32
    40 37 24 30 11 40 37 40 40  5 10 40 40  3 37 40
    2  4  1  3  4  5  2  1  3  3  8  6  7  9  6 10];
X = [20 ; 32 ; 40];
names = {'XXY','ABC','EFG','TXG','ZPF'};

limit = 10; %// The maximum limit of A(4,:). Edit this to 200 for your actual case

%// Find matching 4th row elements
matches = A(4,ismember(A(1:3,:)',X','rows'));

%// Matches are compared against all possible numbers between 1 and limit
matches_pos = ismember(1:limit,matches);

%// Finally get the line 3 results of M
vals = max(2*matches_pos(1:limit/2),matches_pos( (limit/2)+1:end ));
```

Output -

```
vals =
     2     2     2     0     2
```

---

For a better way to present the results, you can use a `struct` -

```
M_struct = cell2struct(num2cell(vals),names,2)
```

Output -

```
M_struct = 
    XXY: 2
    ABC: 2
    EFG: 2
    TXG: 0
    ZPF: 2
```

---

For writing the results to a text file -

```
output_file = 'results.txt'; %// Edit if needed to be saved to a different path
fid = fopen(output_file, 'w+');
for ii=1:numel(names)
    fprintf(fid, '%d %s %d\n',ii, names{ii},vals(ii));
end
fclose(fid);
```

Text contents of the text file would be -

```
1 XXY 2
2 ABC 2
3 EFG 2
4 TXG 0
5 ZPF 2
```

Comment: the code works, but is there any way to have a structure that maps the elements of the second row of M to the elements of the third line?

Comment: @bzak what do you mean? What do you need to do?

Comment: @OlegKomarov: I do not want only the second and third line of M separated. But i need for each name in the second row of M, the corresponding result of the third line!

Comment: @OlegKomarov: In my real problem, I have 100 names. So I need an outcome where I can see for each name the corresponding result.

Comment: @bzak Check out the edit, if that's how you intend to present the results?

Comment: @Divakar: Ok. The result is better in this form. How i can save the result in a text file and adding before the names the values between 1 and 5?

Comment: @bzak How about one column for the `names` and another for the values (the third row of M)? So, a 2-column text file?

Comment: @Divakar: I also need another column to values between 1 and 5.

Comment: @Divakar: Perfect, and sorry if I ask too much detail :)

Comment: @bzak haha that's okay! Guess we all are picky at times :)

Answer (score 0):

A `bsxfun()` based approach.

Suppose your inputs are (where `N` can be set to 200):

```
A = [20 52 70 20 52 20 52 20 20 10 52 20 11  1 52 20
     32 24 91 44 60 32 24 32 32 12 11 32  2  5 24 32
     40 37 24 30 11 40 37 40 40  5 10 40 40  3 37 40
      2  4  1  3  4  5  2  1  3  3  8  6  7  9  6 10]
X = [20; 32; 40]  
N = 10; 

% Match first 3 rows and return 4th 
idxA   = all(bsxfun(@eq, X, A(1:3,:)));
Amatch = A(4,idxA);

% Match [1:5; 5:10] to 4th row
idxZX = ismember([1:N/2; N/2+1:N], Amatch)
idxZX =
     1     1     1     0     1
     1     0     0     0     1 

% Return M3
M3 = max(bsxfun(@times, idxZX, [2;1])) 
M3 =
     2     2     2     0     2
```